# How can I send information when a order is completed to my own POS?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, actions, rest-api

I have a POS made in PHP using OOP. Also I have my e-commerce in WordPress. So I would like to send the data when a order is completed to my POS.

I already looked up for add_action and the hook of Woocommerce order completed. So now I'm stuck about how to send the information to the POS.

Some ideas to research a bit more? I saw the API of Woocommerce, but my question is how can I make it automatically? The API could work for this?

Comment: Your POS would need an API that you can use. The WooCommerce API is for sending data _to_ WooCommerce. If you developed the POS yourself, then you'd need to make the API. WordPress/WooCommerce wouldn't be involved.

Comment: Oh excellent! So I just have to create the POS API and send the info by that way..

Comment: Yes as Jacob said you could do that, as a side note. When asking questions on here you will be more likely to get assistance if you provide more details., I.e. what POS system, where is WordPress hosted,  is pos in cloud or hosted on prem.

Comment: Thanks Falz for the note! I'll keep it in mind